# Count Number of occurrence at each line

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have the following file

```
ENST001 ENST002 4 4 4 88 9 9
ENST004 3 3 3 99 8 8
ENST009 ENST010 ENST006 8 8 8 77 8 8
```

Basically I want to count how many times ENST* is repeated in each line so the expected results is

```
2
1
3
```

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Make sure to accept Zsolt's answer as the correct one by clicking on the check mark left of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (and see it [in action here](http://ideone.com/1rleL)):

```
awk '{print gsub("ENST[0-9]+","")}' INPUTFILE
```